# display echo message on same line as form

Tags: php, forms, echo

How do I display the echo message on the same line as the the form?

[Live version](http://33tpm.com/save_to_file/)

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">Correo: <input type="text" name="mail"><input type="submit" name="Suscribir" value="Suscribir"></form>
<?php
$email = $_POST['mail'];
//the data
$data = "$email\n";
//open the file and choose the mode
$fh = fopen("users.txt", "a");
fwrite($fh, $data);
//close the file
fclose($fh);

if (count($_POST)>0) echo "Suscripcion dado de alta"; 

?>
```

Thank you

Comment: this is HTML related question only, it has nothing to do with PHP or echo. You have to use HTML to format your pages, echo cannot format them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the css `display:inline` attribute on your form :

```
<form style="display:inline-block;">
```

Or put your php into your `<form>`